# Why int64 type can not be applied with rolling?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data:

```
                    Date        Time        Last    Volume
2019-03-01 20:36:00 2019-03-01  20:36:00    11626   94
2019-03-01 20:39:00 2019-03-01  20:39:00    11629   102
2019-03-01 20:42:00 2019-03-01  20:42:00    11631   151
2019-03-01 20:45:00 2019-03-01  20:45:00    11630   141
2019-03-01 20:48:00 2019-03-01  20:48:00    11629   100
2019-03-01 20:51:00 2019-03-01  20:51:00    11628   77
2019-03-01 20:54:00 2019-03-01  20:54:00    11627   165
2019-03-01 20:57:00 2019-03-01  20:57:00    11633   265
2019-03-01 21:00:00 2019-03-01  21:00:00    11633   1
2019-03-01 21:03:00 2019-03-01  21:03:00    11629   19
```

it was imported from a cvs file
and I converted the values using:

```
data['Last']=data['Last'].astype(np.int64)
data['Volume']=data['Volume'].astype(np.int64)
```

and `data.info()` is:

```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> DatetimeIndex: 160104 entries,
> 2017-01-02 07:00:00 to 2019-03-01 21:03:00 Data columns (total 4
> columns): Date      160104 non-null datetime64[ns] Time      160104
> non-null object Last      160104 non-null int64 Volume    160104
> non-null int64 dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(1)
```

when trying to create a lambda function like this:

```
outcomes = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index)
ma_5 = lambda x: x.rolling(5).mean()
outcomes['f06'] = data.Volume.apply(ma_5).apply(np.log)
```

I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

so although I did convert the float to int64, function can not be applied.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because apply takes the function it receives as an argument and calls it with each element of the series.

You are simply looking for `outcomes['f06'] = data.Volume.rolling(5).mean().apply(np.log)`

Comment: it's working but I am not sure i fully understand the explanation.